# The tag 'ChromiumWebBrowser' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf'

Tags: cefsharp

I am attempting to add a CefSharp control to an AnyCPU project.  I have followed the instructions here: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714 and I thought I had everything working correctly.  I pushed my changes to to SVN and then checked out a clean copy.

The first time I attempted to build using that clean copy, I received this error:

```
error MC3074: The tag 'ChromiumWebBrowser' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf'. Line 18 Position 14.
```

as a result of this error, several other libraries fail to compile.  If I attempt to build again, everything compiles fine.

I ran a diagnostic build, and, it appears that the CefSharp packages are in fact being installed from NuGet prior to this error and, the error occurs during MarkupCompilePass1.

This seems very, very similar to this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/4158, however, in that case, it sounds as if the problem was resolved by switching from package.config to PackageReference, but, that approach did not seem to fix my error.

I have read https://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2014/03/06/migrate-away-from-msbuild-based-nuget-package-restore.html as amaintland suggested in the issue I mentioned above, and, unless I'm misunderstanding, it's not a solution that I can use.  For the time being, out continuous integration runs on CruiseControl (which isn't mentioned as a tool that supports automatic package restore out of the box), and we're stuck on VS 2013.

Right now the only option that I can find that seems like it might work is checking the NuGet packages into SVN.  This is a last resort solution for me, but, lacking a better option, I don't know what to do.

If anyone has any insights or suggested steps, I would really appreciate the advice.

Comment: If you are using vs2013 how exactly did you change to package references? Did you try switching to the newer restore method? You can probably run a command line nuget restore as a prebuild task.

Comment: You should probably give your question a more meaningful title and add some more tags so a wider audience sees it also

Comment: I probably wasn't specific enough.  We're stuck on the VS2013 toolset... newer toolsets cause runtime problems with one of the libraries we are using even though the build works.  So, I opened the solution in VS2017, switched to project references and tried it that way.  Thanks for the advice on tagging and title... I've been reading SO for years, but, haven't ever needed to post until I started working in the Windows world.

Comment: After re-reading that blog a few times and clicking through a few of the links in it, I've come to a much better understanding of how NuGet Restore works.  You're right, we could switch to a newer restore method and that would fix our local builds.  Theoretically, we could update our CI system to run a command line restore before the build, but the process of modifying our config is less that user friendly.  We plan to move to Azure DevOps in the next few months, so, for the time being, we've decided to check into source control and fix the tech debt in a while.